# Can I disable magereport and magescan scanning for my website?

Tags: magento-1.9.4.0, magereport

I have a **Magento 1 website** and I don't want [magereport](http://magereport.com) or [magescan](https://magescan.com/) to be able to scan this website.

**How can I do this?**

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Rakesh, is the question how to prevent Magereport from scanning your website?

Comment: @Bono yes correct i want to disable my website scan to magereport and magescan

Answer (score 3):

As far as Magereport is concerned you can [block scans by blocking the `magereport` user-agent](https://www.magereport.com/page/faq#can_I_control_what_sites_are_scanned). You can do this in your nginx or apache config for example.

For nginx:

```
if ($http_user_agent = "magereport"){
    return 403;
}
```

For apache (make sure `a2enmod rewrite` is enabled):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  ^.*magereport.*$
RewriteRule . - [R=403,L]
```

Please make sure you restart the respective service once you've made these changes.

For mage scan the same goes. [You can block it by blocking the `Mage Scan` user-agent.](https://magescan.com/about) You can follow the same steps as above, but change the user-agent correctly.

Disclaimer: I work on magereport.

Comment: not working for me

Comment: @RakeshDonga any specific reason it's not working? Are you using Nginx or Apache, are they returning any errors? What does the access log say when you try to scan your website with magereport/magescan?

Comment: @bone i am using apache and i want to not scan my website to both tool means i want to disable it or block it and i have your code added in htacesss but still not any effect

Comment: @RakeshDonga just so we're on the same page, could you specify what you mean with  "there's no effect"? Do you mean you still see it in the access logs, or do you mean scanning with the tools still works? If so, are you sure `a2enmod rewrite` is enabled?

Comment: yes my server team told me mode_rewrite allready enable and your code is applied in my htacess file but still my website scanning magereort..

Comment: and i am using centos may be this is not affecting

Answer (score 0):

Please add below two line into your magento 1 setup .htaccess file and try to scan your website from magereport or magescan.

```
Deny from magescan.com
Deny from magereport.com
```

Comment: yes i have try that not working still: https://prnt.sc/qkodae

Comment: Ok, let me try other way and update you soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable access from .htaceess files, see below 2 example for reference.

In the following example, all IP addresses and domains are accepted, except for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx and example.com:

## allow all except those indicated here

```
<Files *>
order allow,deny
allow from all
deny from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
deny from .*example\.com.*
</Files>
```

This next example provides steps to block unwanted visitors based on the referring domain. Simply replace "baddomain01″ and "baddomain02″ with the offending domains of your choice:

## block visitors referred from indicated domains

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} baddomain01\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} baddomain02\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Below I've taken from magereport website

- These are the current production IPs for Magereport probe servers.
- They change often, so if you want to update your firewall, you might
  want to automate this.

  - 188.166.64.179
  - 178.62.230.112

Try above method and let us know if it is working for you.

Comment: i have try your code but not working for me : https://prnt.sc/qls41z

Comment: @RakeshDonga when you scan your website with magereport check your access logs also to check from which IP this requests was generated so you can deny those IP addresses.